# Flask secured endpoint authentication flow

Tags: python, flask, jwt, authorization

I am new to Flask and web development and have been trying to understand how authentication and secured endpoints work. When looking at other websites that have authentication for user login I see that there is an access token and a refresh token. From my basic understanding, the access token is used to access secured endpoints and when the access token expires the refresh token is used to generate another access token from the authentication service.

I have found a few tutorials and have been trying to implement my own token-based authentication but I don't quite understand how the token is passed to the client (ie. Browser) to be utilized for the secure endpoints automatically via the headers. The following bit of code is utilized for the login route and the view function, after confirming the username and password, generates a jwt token. When using an application like Postman I can use the "Auth" setting and type in a username and password which is what gets stored in request.authorization. For testing purposes, I am just sending the same info via a GET request. In my code, I try redirecting to my /test endpoint which requires you to have a valid token but all the tutorials just return the token itself.

```
@auth_bp.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    # Fetching authorization information from header
    # auth = request.authorization
    # username = auth.username
    # password = auth.password
    username = request.args.get('username')
    password = request.args.get('password')

    token = ''

    # Fetching row corresponding to user in database
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    if not username or not password:
        return make_response(
            'Username/Password field is missing data.',
            401,
            {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required!"'},
        )
    if not user:
        return make_response(
            'Username/Password do not match.',
            401,
            {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required!"'},
        )

    # Checking hashed password in database to password user passed in auth
    if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        # Generate a token
        token = jwt.encode(
            {
                'public_id': user.public_id,
                'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30),
            },
            current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'],
        )
    else:
        return make_response(
            'Username/Password do not match.',
            401,
            {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required!"'},
        )

    return redirect(url_for('auth.test'))
```

In all of the tutorials, the user always returns the token variable and so when you hit the endpoint via Postman the user is responsible for copying the token and manually adding a header value called x-access-token and setting it equal to the token that was generated. They also create a decorator that verifies if the x-access-token is in the header and if it is they decode the value to query the DB for the particular user info. The verify_token decorator does what I just mentioned

```
def verify_token(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def verify(*args, **kwargs):

        # Check to see if a token is in the headers and if so fetch it
        if 'x-access-token' in request.headers:
            token = request.headers.get('x-access-token')
        else:
            return jsonify({'result': 'Missing token. Login required'})

        # Token is in the headers, need to validitate
        try:
            decode_token_params = jwt.decode(
                token, current_app.config['SECRET_KEY']
            )
            user = User.query.filter_by(
                public_id=decode_token_params.public_id
            ).first()
        except jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError:
            return jsonify({'result': 'Invalid Token. Login required'})
        except jwt.exceptions.ExpiredSignatureError:
            return jsonify({'result': 'Expired Token. Login required'})

        # pass the user SQLAlchemy object to classes that require it
        return func(user, *args, **kwargs)

    return verify
```

I get this part, but what I don't understand is how the token gets passed to each secured endpoint outside of Postman and us manually setting the header value. When I try to modify the header after it says that the headers are immutable and so I cannot manually set the x-access-token to the jwt token that was generated. Is it standard procedure to just print out the token? Is the UI supposed to take the response and set the header on each request the user makes? Or is the token supposed to be stored in a session or cookie? I am really confused.

Also I am a bit confused with the request.authorization line as well. When I use Postman and login with my credentials for "Auth" it populates the Authorization header but when a user logs in via the UI its usually a post request and so this Authorization header wouldn't be set or used, correct?